# How to Get Absolute Path of Currently Selected Item in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, view, qtreeview

I have a simple QTreeView with a QFileSystemModel pointing to the root directory:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTreeView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
    QString dir("/");
    model->setRootPath(dir);
    QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView();
    tree->setModel(model);
    tree->setRootIndex(model->index((dir)));
    tree->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

It displays something like this:
[image]

The item I have selected above is `/usr/lib/clang`. How can I get the absolute path of the currently selected item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()` to obtain selected indexes and `fileSystemModel->filePath()` to get path for these indexes.

Comment: QTreeView::selectedIndexes is protected, so the only way to call it is to write a class that derives from QTreeView.

Comment: +Pavel, works fine.  `QModelIndexList list = ui.treeViewCalib->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();`

Answer (score 0):

```
on_tree_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    model->filePath(index)
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this code works and how you came about deciding what to do .

Comment: This is not precise enough, and so... imcomprehensible and unhelpful